# Adding an exception to IE proxy settings to allow connection to Exchange Online

Tags: windows, powershell, proxy, exchange-server

I'm hoping someone can help. Any advice appreciated.

**Summary:**

Internet access was recently blocked for domain admin accounts. However various scripts we run, while logged into our admin accounts, create a remote connection to Exchange Online using `Connect-ExchangeOnline`.

Internet access is blocked via a group policy which applies proxy settings to IE for any connection except local.

**What I've Tried:**

I've tried adding various Microsoft domains to the exceptions list within the GPO to no avail- see the official list I used here. I've added a few test exceptions (google.com) etc which do work after a gpupdate.

I am using the `-PSSessionOptions` switch with IEConfig as the `-ProxyAccessType`.

When I try to connect I'm receiving a generic error as expected: "New-ExoPSSession : An error occurred while sending the request".

The domains I've added to the exception list are (I realise some of these are contradictory but just wanted to cover all bases as fairly new to this): *.outlook.com; *.outlook.office.com; .outlook.office365.com; *.outlook.*; *.office365.com; *.microsoftonline.com; *.onmicrosoft.com; *. *.onmicrosoft.com

Does anyone have any idea what I'm missing? Any advice appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: If your account is blocked by the proxy then you'll need to fix this either by bypassing the proxy, setting a rule on the proxy to allow the accounts to connect to those addresses specifically or use an account which is authorised to connect externally. I don't see how adding anything in the GPO will help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Adding exceptions in the GPO settings will allow connections out to certain IP addresses or domains. For example, I added an exception for 'google.com' in. Prior to adding this, I could not reach google.com on my admin account. After adding this, I could reach google.com.

The GPO will block any connection going out from our admin accounts EXCEPT to addresses in the exception list. So adding entries there will absolutely make a difference- as tested by myself. Proxies are absolutely capable of allowing certain connections to be made. I hope this clarified things.

Comment: In that case, Microsoft should have a list of sites you need to allow. I'll warn you that it is probably huge as MS now assume that you have endpoint security rather than proxy servers. We all now that's not how companies work but there it is - in our organisation we allow O365 traffic to bypass proxy completely.. You could also try to see where it's trying to connect to using Wireshark.